# Last two elements in dictionary are skipped while inserting key/value pairs from a file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add all the key value pairs from a .txt document into a dictionary and the first two elements of the dictionary are getting skipped for some reason. I have a simple text file that reads

> 1:One
>   2:Two
>   3:Three
>   4:Four
>   5:Five
>   6:Six
>   7:Seven
>   8:Eight
>   9:Nine
>   10:Ten

I have a dictionary declared as:

```
Dictionary<String,String> Test = new Dictionary<String,String>();
```

and a List for testing purposes as:

```
List<String> questionsList = new List<String>();
List<String> possibleAnswers = new List<String>();
```

Code that reads file:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FilePath))
{
   String keyValue;

   char[] delimiterChars = {':'};

   while (!sr.EndOfStream)
   {
       keyValue = sr.ReadLine();
       String[] parts = keyValue.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
       Test.Add(parts[0], parts[1]); 
       questionsList.Add(parts[0]);
       possibleAnswers.Add(parts[1]);
  }
}
```

When I debug the program is shows that the Test dictionary count is 8 when it should be 10 and is populated as follows:

> [0]    {[3, Three]}
>   [1]     {[4, Four]}
>   [2]     {[5, Five]}
>   [3]     {[6, Six]}
>   [4]     {[7, Seven]
>   [5]     {[8, Eight]}
>   [6]     {[9, Nine]}
>   [7]     {[10, Ten]}

But the questionsList and possibleAnswer List holds all the values they're supposed to from reading the file. Can someone please give me some insight on this, i'm sure i'm just missing something stupid. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Try loading your file with `File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)` - it gives you an array of strings, one for each line. Possibly your problem is around the StreamReader.

Comment: i tried exactly your code,and get Test.Count 10, are u sure it's 8?? can you share full code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. I just wanted to point but that your code for the `Dictionary` can be greatly simplified like this:

```
var dictionary = File.ReadAllLines(file)
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Split(':')[0], 
                                   x => x.Split(':')[1]);
```

Comment: This way is much better than what I was doing. It's returning 9 elements now but i'm not sure why it's still leaving one out?

Comment: I'm extremely sorry, there was some code in my ToString() method that removed objects from the dictionary which is why it was returning 9. Thank you very much for your help.